# Scanner error Symbol not found

Tags: java

I have imported the java class but i keep getting this error with the following code

Error: C:\Users\xiangzheng\Desktop\passoff\P70.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        String a = scanner.next;

Code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(sentence);
        scanner.useDelimiter(" ");
        String a = scanner.next;
```

Comment: Can you post the Scanner class. Is there a public variable 'next' in Scanner ?

Comment: Yea sorry my bad guys i had insert on and over wrote the () that should of came after the next.

Answer (score 6):

Probably you are just missing the parenthesis from the method invokation, try with

```
String a = scanner.next();
```

scanner.next tries to access to an instance variable which doesn't exist for `Scanner` class.

Answer (score 2):

Change `scanner.next` to `scanner.next()`

Answer (score 2):

I believe next is a method, not a variable.

Try this and let me know if it works.

```
String a = scanner.next();
```